# Accrued time calculation goes to 48 hours instead of 24 hours EXCEL VBA

Tags: vba, date, time, excel-2010

This has been stressing me out.
I have a sheet that the user enters time, either manually or automatically with a button.
The time is entered in column B in 24 hour format.

The button code is:

```
Sub TimeStamp()
    If ActiveCell.Column = 2 Then
        ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="80286"
        With Selection
            .Value = VBA.DateTime.Now
            .NumberFormat = "hh:mm"
        End With
        ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="80286"
    End If
End Sub
```

The formula on the worksheet for this is as follows:

START TIME V16 `=CEILING(IF(TIMEVALUE(TEXT(B16,"hh:mm"))=B16, O9 + B16, B16),0.5/24)` gets the time entered with the button or manually. Its format is `custom (m/d/yyyy h:mm AM/PM)`.

CURRENT ENTERED TIME V17 `=IF('TR2'!B10='TR2'!B11,'TR2'!B11,'TR2'!B10)` gets the last entry in column B from the formula `=IFERROR(LOOKUP(2,1/(B16:B63<>""),B16:B63),"0:00")` Its format is `custom (hh:mm)`.

END TIME V18 `=CEILING(IF(TIMEVALUE(TEXT(IF('TR2'!B10='TR2'!B11,'TR2'!B11,'TR2'!B10),"hh:mm"))=IF('TR2'!B10='TR2'!B11,'TR2'!B11,'TR2'!B10), TODAY() + V17, IF('TR2'!B10='TR2'!B11,'TR2'!B11,'TR2'!B10)),0.5/24)` get the time entered either from the button or manually. Its format is `custom (m/d/yyyy h:mm AM/PM)`.

ACCRUED TIME V20 `=IF(V19>0,MAX(0,(V19-V16)*24),MAX(0,(V18-V16)*24))`. Formatted as `general`.

This all works fine, my issue is when the workbook is saved when the time is from `m/d/yyyy 0:00` - `m/d/yyyy 23:59`, this switches the end date to the next day, which is fine as all my calculations for accrued time is 24. (`7/25/2020 0:00` - `7/26/20202 0:00`)

The workbook will be opened in future so I have to try to remove the `Today()` function from cell V18. So, when it saves it changes these values with VBA:

```
Worksheets("TR").Range("V21").Value = Format(CDate(Worksheets("TR").Range("O10").Value), "mm/dd/yyyy")
Worksheets("TR").Range("V19").Formula = "=CEILING(V21 + TIMEVALUE(TEXT(V17,""hh:mm"")),0.5/24)"
```

O10's formula is `=IF(V19>0, V19,V18)` and is formatted as a `date (month day, year)`.

V19 `=CEILING(V21 + TIMEVALUE(TEXT(V17,"hh:mm")),0.5/24)` which displays as `2/27/2020 12:00 AM`. Formatted as `custom (m/d/yyyy h:mm AM/PM)`
V20's formula `=IF(V19>0,MAX(0,(V19-V16)*24),MAX(0,(V18-V16)*24))` will display `48`.
V21 will display `2020-07-26`. Formatted as `Date`.

Now, this is where my grief is. Instead of using `7/26/2020 0:00` for 24 hours Excel changes it to `7/27/2020 0:00` for 48 hours.

Further information; this sheet can also use an old date to. Instead of using today, you can edit the start (entered manually) and end date, edit end date uses this code from a userform:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    If IsDate(Edit_Date.TextBox2.Value) = False Then
        MsgBox "Date entered is not valid." & vbNewLine & "Enter date as ""MONTH - END DAY - YEAR.""", , "DATE ERROR"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    ask = Format(CDate(TextBox2.Text), "mmmm/dd/yyyy")
    If MsgBox("Change end date to " & ask & "?", vbYesNo, "EDIT END DATE") = vbNo Then Exit Sub
    Worksheets("TR").Unprotect Password:="80286"
    Worksheets("TR").Range("V21").Value = Edit_Date.TextBox2.Value
    Worksheets("TR").Range("V19").Formula = "=CEILING(V21 + TIMEVALUE(TEXT(V17,""hh:mm"")),0.5/24)"
    Worksheets("TR").Protect Password:="80286"
    Unload Me
End Sub
```

When I try to fix one to show the proper accrued time, the other function breaks.  Is there a better, more efficient way to do this? Thank you for your time, and I apologize for the wall of text, I wanted to show as much as I could.

Answer (score 0):

My girlfriend gave me a stroke of genius and I was unnecessarily over complicating this issue. She said if `Today()` is creating the issue, remove it, so I did.

Changes to the formulas and VBA are as follows, posting in case someone is curious of the solution.

Enter Time Button:

```
Sub TimeStamp()
        If ActiveCell.Column = 2 Then
            ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="80286"
            With Selection
                .Value = Time
                .NumberFormat = "h:mm"
            End With
            ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="80286"
        End If
    End Sub
```

START DATE V16 `=CEILING(IF(TIMEVALUE(TEXT(B16,"h:mm"))=B16, O9 + B16, B16),0.5/24)` still determines if the time was entered manually or with the button and rounds up to the nearest half hour.

CURRENT TIME V17 `=CEILING(IF('TR2'!B10='TR2'!B11,'TR2'!B11,'TR2'!B10),0.5/24)` again, pulled from the cell to determine the last entry B15 `=IFERROR(LOOKUP(2,1/(B16:B63<>""),B16:B63),"0:00")` and rounds up to the nearest half hour.

END DATE V18 `=V19+V17` combines date from V19 and time from V17.

DATE TAKEN FROM START DATE V19 `=INT(V16)`.

ACCRUED TIME V20 `=MAX(0,(V18-V16)*24)`.

The changes to the userform to change the END DATE:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    If IsDate(Edit_Date.TextBox2.Value) = False Then
        MsgBox "Date entered is not valid." & vbNewLine & "Enter date as ""MONTH - END DAY - YEAR.""", , "DATE ERROR"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    ask = Format(CDate(TextBox2.Text), "mmmm/dd/yyyy")
    If MsgBox("Change end date to " & ask & "?", vbYesNo, "EDIT END DATE") = vbNo Then Exit Sub
    Worksheets("TR").Unprotect Password:="80286"
    Worksheets("TR").Range("V19").Value = Edit_Date.TextBox2.Value
    Worksheets("TR").Protect Password:="80286"
    Unload Me
End Sub
```

The save code was removed.

I hope this helps anyone that needs it. I thank those who read over and considered a response.